# How to use extension in xsd when order of element is important

Tags: xsd

I have some complexType element which is parent of some element:

```
<xs:complexType name="elementParent">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:String" />
        <xs:element name="c" type="xs:String" />
</xs:complexType>
```

now I want to create anothex complex type which will be extension of my parent. Problem is in order. First element should be a then b and then c. I just know this option where order will be b c a which I dont want:

```
<xs:complexType name="elementChild">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="elementParent">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="a" type="xs:String" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<xs:extension>` creates a type which is a sequence containing first the base type and then the explicit content defined in `<xs:extension>`. If you only want to add new elements preceding the elements of another type, you could define the common elements as an `<xs:group>` and then refer to that group in both of the type definitions.

Something like this:

```
<!-- common elements defined as a group -->
<xs:group name="elementGroup">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<!-- group is referred to in element type definitions -->
<xs:element name="elementParent">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="elementGroup" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="elementChild">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:group ref="elementGroup" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```